# Sum of non-standard series

Tags: calculus

Compute $$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{((-1)^n - 3)^n}$$

I think that I should show that this series is convergence. I have that

$$ a_n = \frac{1}{((-1)^n - 3)^n} =  \begin{cases} - \frac{1}{4^n} \quad n=2k+1 \\ \frac{1}{2^n} \qquad n=2k  \end{cases} $$ for $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

Hence $ \sum_n \frac{-1}{4^n}$ and $\sum_n \frac{1}{2^n}$ are convergance so $\sum_n a_n$ is too convergance. If I would like compute this infinity sum, I noticed that $$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{((-1)^n - 3)^n} = - \left(\frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{2^6} + \frac{1}{2^{10}} +\frac{1}{2^{14}}+ ... \right) + \frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{2^4}+\frac{1}{2^6}+\frac{1}{2^8}+... = \frac{1}{15}$$
This is sum of two geometric progressions.

Does it work?

Comment: Yes, it does work.

Comment: But, can't re-arranging the order of terms in an infinite series change the resulting sum? (I really don't know...)

Comment: @anorton, not id the convergence is absolute, as in this case, though this isn't completely clear from the above.

Answer (score 2):

In order to split the sum up as you have done, you must show that the original sum is absolutely convergent, otherwise rearrangements don't always yield the same sum.

You can show absolute convergence using the inequality $4^{-n}<2^{-n}$ and the comparison test.

After that, all of your work looks great.